# ag grid column labels not included while exporting data

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-vue

Whenever I try to export data from ag grid in pivot mode the column labels row is not included in the export file.

```
<ag-grid-vue
  style="width: 100%; height: 600px"
  class="ag-theme-balham mt-3"
  id="myGrid"
  :gridOptions="gridOptions"
  :defaultColDef="defaultColDef"
  :columnDefs="columnDefs"
  :pivotMode="true"
  :rowGroupPanelShow="rowGroupPanelShow"
  :pivotPanelShow="pivotPanelShow"
  :pivotColumnGroupTotals="pivotColumnGroupTotals"
  :pivotRowTotals="pivotRowTotals"
  :autoGroupColumnDef="autoGroupColumnDef"
  :sideBar="true"
  :rowData="rowData"
  ></ag-grid-vue>
```

```
import { AgGridVue } from "ag-grid-vue";
import "ag-grid-enterprise";
```

Currently I'm trying to call the export function on btn click, The function is as follows

```
onBtnExportDataAsExcel() {
      this.gridOptions.api.exportDataAsExcel({ columnGroups: true });
},
```

Is there a way to download the column labels along with columns data, or do I need to import some ag grid module for this to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ans given by @pratik is right. But the import that you are using is maybe wrong. Visit this [link](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-excel/).

Answer (score 2):

Since you have not provided the code for how you have implemented export function, I can take a guess.

You will have to pass the params object with `columnGroups: true` like this -

```
this.gridApi.exportDataAsExcel({ columnGroups: true });
```

This should export all the grouped headers.
Pivot example from the [docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-pivoting/#example-api).

If you are looking to change the context menu export implementation, it is a 2 step process.

1.Create a function

```
exportDataAsExcel() {
  this.gridApi.exportDataAsExcel({ columnGroups: true });
}
```

2. Customize the context menu and provide this function in the action parameter.

Comment: I tried this, the data is exported to excel but, the column labels are still not included.

Comment: can you post your export function implementation? Is it throught a button or through context menu?

Comment: It is through a button. I have added the function, do check.

Answer (score 0):

It's fixed in version 25.3.0.
So you don't need to do as @pratik said any more

and u can check it from here.
https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-changelog/?fixVersion=25.3.0